# How to upload .md5 and .sha1 checksum files to bintray?

Tags: java, scala, curl, sbt, bintray

I've created repository, uploaded a `.jar` there, and now trying to upload an `.md5` and `.sha1` checksums via web UI, but bintray gives me an error

> No files were uploaded. Signature files cannot be uploaded when repository auto-signing is enabled.

I've tried with curl, and it says `success`, but no files are actually uploaded.
Here is the command

```
curl -T package-version.jar.sha1 -uUSER:APIKEY https://api.bintray.com/content/USER/REPO/PACKAGE/VERSION/package-version.jar.sha1
```

I've tried with jfrog cli:

```
jfrog bt u package-version.jar.sha1 REPO/PACKAGE/VER/`
```

but still an error

```
{
  "status": "failure",
  "totals": {
    "success": 0,
    "failure": 0
  }
}
[Error] Bintray response: 405 Not Allowed
```

Also, when I'm uploading a jar with curl, I got a warning

> {"warn":"The target repository is configured to auto-sign, but the private key requires a passphrase and none was provided. No files will be signed"}

even though I've checked that there all gpg settings in 'Edit Profile -> Repositories -> REPO -> Edit` are disabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you can't upload `.sha1` and `.md5` files to Bintray.

But the good news is that Bintray calculates the `.sha1` for you, so all you have to do is just append `.sha1` to the url, e.g.

```
curl -L https://api.bintray.com/content/USER/REPO/PACKAGE/VERSION/package-version.jar.sha1
```

just check that your file (without `.sha1`) is actually available on this path